# Deserializing JSON text with inside's Array in Visual basic webservice

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, web-services, json-deserialization

I have a problem when Deserializing this json string:

```
{
"UserName": "Person1",
"TechOpinion": "Under Repair",
"CodeStatus": "0",
"DateYear": "2016",
"TechCode": "Person2",
"CReception": [{
    "CodeRecep": "146001"
}, {
    "CodeRecep": "146002"
}, {
    "CodeRecep": "146003"
}, {
    "CodeRecep": "146004"
}]
}
```

I want to call an stored procedure with root values and one of CodeRecep values each time(by number of CodeRecep values the stored procedure will call {{4 times in this sample}} )
I write two class for json type in two seperate .class files
first one to hold root values as follow:

```
Public Class ArrayJSONParameter
Dim _UserName As String
Dim _TechOpinion As String
Dim _CodeStatus As String
Dim _DateYear As String
Dim _TechCode As String
Dim _CReception As CodeReceptions



Public Property UserName() As String
    Get
        Return _UserName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _UserName = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property TechOpinion() As String
    Get
        Return _TechOpinion
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _TechOpinion = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property CodeStatus() As String
    Get
        Return _CodeStatus
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _CodeStatus = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property DateYear() As String
    Get
        Return _DateYear
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _DateYear = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property TechCode() As String
    Get
        Return _TechCode
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _TechCode = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property CReception() As CodeReceptions
    Get
        Return _CReception
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As CodeReceptions)
        _CReception = value
    End Set
End Property


End Class
```

and the second one to hold inside array as follow:

```
Public Class CodeReceptions
Dim _CodeRece As String
Public Property CodeRecep() As String
    Get
        Return _CodeRece
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _CodeRece = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

my main method code in webservice is :

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function JsonSample(ByVal jsonTxt As String) As String
    Dim _JSONArray As ArrayJSONParameter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ArrayJSONParameter)(jsonTxt)

    Return "sample text" '_JSONArray.UserName
End Function
```

but when i'm try to execute the webservice with my json string i face this error:

```
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'CodeReceptions' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {&quot;name&quot;:&quot;value&quot;}) to deserialize correctly.
    To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {&quot;name&quot;:&quot;value&quot;}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List&lt;T&gt; that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
    Path 'CReception', line 1, position 119.
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureArrayContract(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 823
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 848
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 293
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 1018
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 2393
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 485
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 291
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 196
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 823
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 863
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 820
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value) in C:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Working-Signed\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 757
       at JSONWS.JsonSample(String jsonTxt)
```

i spend last two days to read Deserializing threads in internet but similar threads use simple json text but my problem is inside's array.
i cant find the right answer so please help me on that.
why i get that error? and beside how can i access inside array values in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CReception` property needs to be an array of `CodeReceptions`, not a single `CodeReceptions`:

```
Dim _CReception As CodeReceptions()
'...
Public Property CReception() As CodeReceptions()
    Get
        Return _CReception
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As CodeReceptions())
        _CReception = value
    End Set
End Property
```

It could be a `List(Of CodeReceptions)` instead, if you prefer.

Comment: thnx alot Mark. you save my life! i'm realy thanks of your response time and YES my code works fine. please help me more on selecting array or list. in your opinion which one is better in my case.

Comment: If you are going to add items to the `CReception` collection, I would use a `List`.  If not, it's probably down to personal preference.  Personally, I almost always use lists instead of arrays.

Comment: thanks Mark. I think I'll need to add some items in future but not right now. but it's better that i use item instead of array from now. thanks for sharing experiences.